# Is there such a lightweight IDE for Python as RStudio is for R?

Tags: python, ide, debugging, r

Responsiveness, interactive `ipython` console, and versatile, customizable design (not like Jupyter Notebook which locks you into browser); I need full control on editor color scheme, syntax coloring, bracket matching and full debugger support with breakpoints. Great support of scientific plotting is also required.

Do not propose: SpyderIDE (bugged breakpoint support, crashes); JetBrains PyCharm with JupyterNotebooks plugin (doesn't work); SublimeText/LightTable/AtomIDE/VScode (no or limited debugger support).

Something like Geany or CodeBlocks will do, if all requirements are met.

Comment: "Something like Geany or CodeBlocks will do, if all requirements are met." - Have you not already answered your own question? Or have you discounted these tools, too?

Comment: @spikey_richie not supported officially; requires deep knowledge of the IDE itself and the build stack - which is undesired